# Why am I getting "No such file or directory" after install?

Tags: linux, unix, centos, imagemagick

If I command `convert --version` it shows this.

```
bash: /usr/bin/convert: No such file or directory
```

All what I did was this

```
1. $ wget ftp://ftp.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/ImageMagick.tar.gz
2. $ tar xvzf ImageMagick.tar.gz
3. $ cd ImageMagick-6.8.2-10
4. $ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-bzlib=yes --with-fontconfig=yes --with-freetype=yes --with-gslib=yes --with-gvc=yes --with-jpeg=yes --with-jp2=yes --with-png=yes --with-tiff=yes
5. $ make
6. $ make install
```

Answer (score 2):

`/usr/local/bin` is not in `$PATH` by default in CentOS. Either add it in or run `yum install ImageMagick` to install ImageMagick from the CentOS repos.

Comment: Thanks That's true but the problem is yum in my CentOS5.8 can install up to the version 6.2.8:( I'd like to install the latest version.

Comment: That's why I presented it as only one of the options.

Comment: what should I do? `PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/convert`? or `PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin`? then export PATH?

Comment: Neither. That's not where you installed it.

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/convert --version` ?? You should be able to run it like this

Comment: @mcalex it returns this `Version: ImageMagick 6.8.2-10 2013-02-11 Q16.............`

Answer (score 0):

Don't go installing software from source unless strictly necessary. I believe ImageMagick is in CentOS, and GraphicsMagick (a fork from the above) is in [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL)

Answer (score 0):

If you have just installed, try to make sure everything is fine:

```
/usr/local/bin/convert --version
```

Then

```
source /etc/profile
```

Now you can just use :

```
convert --version
```